# Is there any way to extract the actual clock (not frequency) from a monitor?

Tags: c++, frame-rate, monitor

I'm trying to build a high speed 3d printer with a light engine (recognized as monitor by my PC) that has a refresh rate of 30 Hz according to Windows. However, when I'm printing over thousands of layers there a few instances where the pictures are displayed for 66.66 ms not 33.33 ms, because the frequency don't seem to perfectly be in sync. Is there any way to extract the actual clock signals of a monitor such that I can coordinate my program according to the clock of the monitor. Maybe it's unstable.

It would be perfect if there where some kind of library for C++ to detect the single clock signal from the monitor. There must be, since the system and other applications extract the frequency on their own right?

Comment: What library do you use for drawing? I assume you have vsync enabled? I'd try raising the process priority too...

Comment: I'd imagine this is nothing to do with the refresh rate of the monitor, your rendering is simply dropping a frame occasionally

Comment: Many rendering APIs, such as Direct2D and Direct3D, have a feature called VSync, which stands for [vertical synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#Vertical_synchronization). I believe in Direct2D, this is the default, [which can be overridden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/ne-d2d1-d2d1_present_options). However, you will still have to ensure that your program delivers the frame to the monitor in time, for example by giving your process a sufficiently high priority.